# How to prove well-foundedness of Cantorian Ordinals

Tags: set-theory

I am probably misrepresenting history but the classical naive definition
of ordinals was as equivalence classes of well-ordered sets under
order-preserving bijections. The collection of such ordinals is well-ordered
under the order defined by order-preserving injections, being well-ordered
is the whole point of ordinals.

This approach was superseded by the familiar vonNeumann approach which
provides a canonical representation of the equivalence-class based
ordinals by using ordinals defined by *insert-our-favourite-definition-of
an-ordinal* as witnesses.

In the vonNeumann approach to ordinals there is not much to prove
because well-foundedness is essentially built into the definition
or inherited from regularity.

My question relates to how Cantor and his cohort proved the ordinals
were well-founded before the vonNeumann approach took over. How do
you show every nonempty set of ordinals has a minimum when dealing
with equivalence classes.

Translating I think the theorem becomes - *Let $\mathcal{B}$
be a nonempty set of well-ordered sets then there exists a well-ordered
set $M$ and an $A\in\mathcal{B}$ such $M\simeq A$ and for every
$B\in\mathcal{B}$ there is an order-preserving injection from $A$
to $B$.*

Can someone give me a clue for a proof, or tell me if the question
even makes sense? I believe Cantor would have proved this without
the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Cantor would have done it, but we can "locally" construct canonical representatives by embedding everything from $\mathcal{B}$ into an upper bound, such as the supremum. So, there exists

- A well-ordered set $\sup(\mathcal{B})$
- For each $A \in \mathcal{B}$, an order preserving map $I_A : A \to \sup(\mathcal{B})$ identifying $A$ with an initial segment of $\sup(\mathcal{B})$.
- $\sup(\mathcal{B}) = \cup_A \{ \mathrm{image}(I_A) \mid A \in \mathcal{B} \}$

By this device, we can construct a new set
$$\mathcal{B}' = \{ \mathrm{image}(I_A) \mid A \in \mathcal{B} \} $$
If we are asking questions depending only on order types, then we can answer questions about $\mathcal{B}$ by translating them into questions about $\mathcal{B}'$.

(I've omitted dealing with technicalities regarding the case where $\mathcal{B}$ has equivalent objects, since they are irrelevant to the given question, and IMO they are relatively straightforward but tedious)

---

The supremum can be constructed by the following device.

Recall that any two well-ordered sets are comparable. Furthermore, if $A \leq B$, then there is a (unique!) order preserving map $I_{AB}: A \to B$ identifying $A$ with an initial segment of $B$.

First, let $S$ be the disjoint union; that is,

$$ S = \{ (A,a) \mid a \in A \wedge A \in \mathcal{B} \} $$

and define a preordering

$$ (A,a) \leq (B,b) \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases} I_{AB}(a) \leq b & A \leq B
\\ a \leq I_{BA}(b) & B \leq A \end{cases} $$

Then we can take $\sup(\mathcal{B})$ to be the equivalence classes of $S$, where  $x \equiv y$ iff $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$.

$\leq$ will be a well-order on $\sup(\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Thanks Hurkyl for your comprehensive answer. I will work my way through it :)

Answer (score 0):

For any well-orders $C,D$ let $C\sim D$ mean that $C,D$ are order-isomorphic.

Let $<_C$ be a well-order on $C.$ An initial segment of $C$ is $\{p\in C:p<_C  q\}$ for some $q\in C,$ well-ordered by $<_C.$

Let $\mathbb B$ be a non-empty family of well-ordered sets. For each $C\in \mathbb B,$ if no initial segment of $C$ is order-isomorphic  to a member of $\mathbb B$ then   let $f(C)=C.$ Otherwise let $f(C)=\{p\in C:p<_Cq\}$ where $q$ is the $<_C$-least $y\in C$ such that some $D\in \mathbb B$ satisfies $D\sim \{p\in C:p<_Cy\}.$

$(\bullet).$  If $X $ is an initial segment of $f(C)$ then $X$ is also an initial segment of $C,$ and no $E\in  \mathbb B$ satisfies $E\sim X.$

Claim. $f(C) \sim f(D)$ for all $C,D\in \mathbb B.$

Proof. Suppose not. WLOG there is an  order-isomorphism $g:f(D)\to X$ where $X$ is an initial segment of $f(C). $ But there exists $E\in \mathbb B$ and an order-isomorphism $\psi:E\to f(D).$ Then the composite function $(g\psi):E\to X$ is an order-isomorphism, contrary to $(\bullet).$

So take some (any) $C\in \mathbb B$ and some (any) $A\in \mathbb B$ such that $A\sim f(C).$ Then for every $D\in \mathbb B,$ either $A \sim D=f(D)$ or  $A$ is order-isomorphic to  the initial segment $f(D)$ of $D.$

Comment: BTW. The trichotomy rule for well-orders does not require AC.

Comment: In "Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs" by K.Kunen, an initial segment $\{p\in C:p<_Cq\}$  is denoted $\text {pred}(q$) or pred$_C(q)$ or pred$_{<_C}(q)$. ("pred" for predecessors.)

Comment: Great answer @DanielWainfleet thanks